# Multi-Site ExpressionEngine .htaccess Issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a ExpressionEngine install, that is running 2 websites.

Since I have added a domain to point to the second site, I need to update the old links: http://mysite.com/othersite to redirect to http://othersite.com

So, even though http://othersite.com brings up the other site, when I attempt to add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Redirect 301 /othersite http://othersite.com
```

to mysite.com root .htaccess file, it ends up causing a redirect loop for othersite.com

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not entirely clear on all your different redirects. You say mysite is supposed to redirect to othersite, but then you say "even though http://othersite.com brings up the other site (...)". Is othersite also redirecting to mysite? Which URL entered into your browser causes the redirect loop?

Comment: No. mysite.com goes to mysite.com.  othersite.com goes to othersite.com, however...  mysite.com/othersite is where othersite.com resides, so I need to redirect any links to mysite.com/othersite to othersite.com.  However, when I do that (as in the code I posted above), it causes a redirect loop

Comment: Ok, just to get this right: do you really want to redirect people who type `http://mysite.com/othersite` into their browser's address bar to `http://othersite.com`, which then serves files from `http://mysite.com/othersite`? Or do the users only know/type in `othersite` anyway (which will then "secretly" be served from `mysite/othersite`)? (If you redirect people from A to B and then back to A, of course there'll be a loop!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your root `.htaccess` to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/othersite [NC]
RewriteRule ^othersite/(.*)$ http://othersite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You're getting a redirect loop because your rule is active for both the domains.